# Which libraries should be linked to this VTK example?

Tags: c++, vtk

I want to compile [this](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/IO/ReadDICOMSeries) example in vtk, which includes the following include files:

```
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkObjectFactory.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>
#include <vtkActor.h>
// headers needed for this example
#include <vtkImageViewer2.h>
#include <vtkDICOMImageReader.h>
#include <vtkInteractorStyleImage.h>
#include <vtkActor2D.h>
#include <vtkTextProperty.h>
#include <vtkTextMapper.h>
// needed to easily convert int to std::string
#include <sstream>
```

Originally it should be compiled with a `CMakeLists.txt`-file which looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT(ReadDICOMSeries)

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

add_executable(ReadDICOMSeries MACOSX_BUNDLE ReadDICOMSeries)

if(VTK_LIBRARIES)
  target_link_libraries(ReadDICOMSeries ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
else()
  target_link_libraries(ReadDICOMSeries vtkHybrid vtkWidgets)
endif()
```

The problem is: When I simply copy this code and compile it, I get a lot of reference errors (for example: `Undefined reference to 'vtkDICOMImageReader::SetDirectoryName(char const*)'`). This leads me to the assumption that I should link some libraries to it. Unfortunately the CMakeLists-file does not tell me which libraries. How do I find that out?

Comment: When you run CMake, it the VTK installation path the correct one?

Comment: Yes, everything is fine.

Comment: Do you have a problem only on this example, while other works fine? If you have compiled successfully vtk, and use CMake for setting up the project, the libraries to be included are already managed by cmake (thanks to include(${VTK_USE_FILE}), ${VTK_LIBRARIES}). Have you maybe compiled VTK in release mode and tried to compile the example in debug, or the other way around?

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to use CMake, I want to use g++ and add the libraries via -l<xx>. But I don't know which libraries I have to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cmake is really strongly suggested for compiling VTK and related projects, especially as a beginner. I only use CMake, but I got an idea of what happens under the hood by checking the properties of the projects already built. In the example you provided, the CMake file only use "target_link_libraries(ReadDICOMSeries ${VTK_LIBRARIES}" , as far as I understood that it is providing to the linker ALL the libraries built with  vtk.

To see what CMake will load with that instruction, check the file "VTKConfig.cmake" in the vtk build directory. 
If you do it manually, you will also have to include a lot of directories

Answer (score 2):

I managed to figure this out without using CMake directly or having to dig into each individual lib.

1. find a header file or C/CPP file that defines the object that's giving you linker pain.
2. Do a find-in-files of the *.cmake files that came with VTK, searching for that filename.  So in your case, look for `vtkDICOMImageReader`.
3. I found vtkDICOMImageReader in vtkIOKit.cmake, so a decent guess might be libvtkio.

In my case, I was hunting for `vtkDataSetAttributes`, and this method successfully determined it was in vtkFiltering.lib.

If you've already got Cmake set up then doing it correctly might be easier, but I didn't want "set up vtk" to turn into "set up cmake so I can set up vtk" and then into "set up some other thing so I can set up cmake so I can set up vtk".